# Django 1.11 middleware how to redirect properly

Tags: django, django-middleware

I have a difficulty with the middleware that I cannot get to sort out. The project I am working on is supposed to redirect all requests to visit any part of the site to add_company page if the user has not setup its company.  To do this I am writing a custom middleware.  The following code, however, does not work:

```
class ProjectTrackingMiddleWare(MiddlewareMixin):
    ''' 
        Note that this Middleware should come after all other middlewares 
        in order to 
    '''
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        ''' One-time configuration called when the web-server starts '''
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        ''' To be executed on every request.  '''

        the_request = self.process_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)  

        return response

    def process_request(self, request):

        the_user = request.user
        print ('the_user: ', the_user)

        ## CASE 1: User is not authenticated -->  Redirect to login page
        if the_user.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))      #  <-- This part works

         the_company = the_user.userprofile.employer    
        if the_user and not the_company:
            print ('the company: ', the_company)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_profile:add_company'))   #<-- Does NOT redirect correctly

        if the_user.projects.all().count() > 1:
            request.project = the_user.projects.all().order_by('-date_modified')[0]

        return request
```

The middleware does not redirect to add_company page.  Instead, if as a logged-in user who has not setup a project try to visit a page, Django lets me visit the page:

When I try to visit the homepage, the redirect does not happen. But, here is the error if I were to visit `/development/` page on the site:

> Exception Type: TypeError at /development/
>
> Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.

when I look at the context, it is:

```
Variable    Value
context     <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/project/add/">
kwargs      {'autoescape': True}
request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/development/'>
```

It looks like there is a redirect happening when I try to visit `/development/` page as the `url="/project/add/">` suggests it did pickup on the HttpResponseRedirect.

So, here are my questions:
1) It seems like redirecting in the process_request is OK to do, or is it not recommended?  If not, then where do I check for these global variables and redirect the user to properly setup?

2) How do I get the redirect chain similar to what the Client has:

```
client.get(reverse(‘dashboard’), follow = True)
```

Edit 1:
As suggested in Iain's comment, I should have passed the_request to the get_response method.  However, this did not resolve the issue.  Django now complains about HttpResponseRedirect not having the attribute path:

> 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'path'

What makes this odd is that if I were to redirect based on the company existance to the login url, I get this error too, but if I redirect an anonymous user to the login url, I do not get this error:

```
## Redirects successfully when the user is anonymous. If the user is logged-in already, it skips it as expected
if the_user.is_anonymous():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))
### Throws attribute excpetion: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'path'
if not the_company:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))
```

So, it looks like the error has to do with the request object. But, I cannot figure it out at this point.  Any idea?

Comment: `response = self.get_response(request)` should be passing `the_request` instead of `request` here?

Comment: @IainShelvington Gives me a different error `AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'path'` with `request: <WSGIRequest: GET '/project/company/add/'>` and `the_request:  <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/project/company/add/">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I finally fixed this was to use process_view hook.

```
AUTHENTICATION_EXEMPT_URLS = (
                           reverse('accounts:signup').lstrip('/'),   # reverse part returns '/accounts/login' and lstrip('/') drops the '/': 'accounts/login'
                           reverse('accounts:login').lstrip('/'),
                           reverse('accounts:logout').lstrip('/'),
                        )

COMPANY_EXEMPT_URLS =  (   reverse('project_profile:add_company').lstrip('/'), 
                       reverse('accounts:signup').lstrip('/'),
                       reverse('accounts:login').lstrip('/'),
                       reverse('accounts:logout').lstrip('/'),
                   )


class MyRedirectMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):    
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')       # being logged in is required
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        if not request.user.is_authenticated():

            if not any(url for url in AUTHENTICATION_EXEMPT_URLS if url==path):    
            # if the url is not in any of the list's urls, redirect to authentication page
                return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        #  Note that userprofile is created using a signal currently at user_profile/models.py 
        the_company = request.user.userprofile.employer
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and not the_company:
            # user should setup a copmany first:
            if not any( url for url in COMPANY_EXEMPT_URLS if url==path):
                return redirect(reverse('project_profile:add_company'))
```

I should credit a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/DbAzWll4UIA) and thank all of you who took time to help, you are great.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written your middleware doesn't quite make sense. Your `process_request` method is returning a `Response` object, which you're then passing to `get_response`. This is invalid - `get_response` takes a *request*, not a *response*.

Since you want to short-circuit the response in certain cases, you need to skip calling `get_response` entirely if you want to redirect. This means your checks need to happen before `get_response` is called. Something like this:

```
def __call__(self, request):
    # Perform your checks here, and redirect if necessary
    the_user = request.user
    ## CASE 1: User is not authenticated -->  Redirect to login page
    if not the_user:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))
    the_company = the_user.userprofile.employer    
    if not the_company:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_profile:add_company'))  

    if the_user.projects.all().count() > 1:
        request.project = the_user.projects.all().order_by('-date_modified')[0]

    # Now that you've done your checks, let the rest of the request process run
    response = self.get_response(request)  
    return response
```

(drop the `process_request` method as it is no longer used).